# What is the meaning of blissfully in in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in 'the Hindu' which was:

> The Congress, which is meant to be a premier forum for scientists to present and discuss their research, has in recent years become the stage for a series of **blissfully evidence-free** claims about Indian achievements in Science through the ages.

Now consider the part "blissfully evidence-free". Does it mean that one doesn't bother about gathering evidence? Or is it just blissful ignorance towards claims?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter. It's a modification of **blissful ignorance**, indicating that since no evidence is provided for these claims, blissful ignorance can be maintained.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the phrase "ignorance is bliss" is a common three-word expression that could just about qualify as a maxim.

Comment: "Where ignorance is bliss, it is folly to be wise" carries a strong implication that the "ignorance" is deliberate.